# How to define any property of type string excludes some property

Tags: typescript

I want to define dynamic property of type string. However, some predefined property has number type.

How to define such type.

My intention is like:

```
interface User {
  age: number;

  [K: Exclude<string, 'age'>]: string
}
// or 
interface User {
  age: number;

  [K: not in "age"]: string
}
```

Comment: what about making use of a *tuple* defined type, or make use of `let someVar: any;`.